# Error website after installing the language pack

Tags: magento2, language-package

I wanted to install the German language packet from GitHub. `https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack`

Via composer I opened Putty and run first command line:

```
composer require mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack:dev-master
```

after this I wanted deploy via command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE -f
```

and now I see error:
[image]

Page has stopped displaying:
[image]

I have deleted module-core from vendor:

```
rm -rf vendor/mageplaza/module-core
```

and now error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/fsg/domains/aron.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/../mageplaza/module-core/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fsg/domains/aron.pl/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Comment: You can also add this as an answer and accept it later ... maybe this is helpfull for others too :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem follow the steps below.

(depending on the version, it's called **module-core** or **core-m2**):

```
rm -rf vendor/mageplaza/core-m2 
rm -rf app/code/Mageplaza/Core
composer remove mageplaza/core-m2
composer dump-autoload
composer require mageplaza/module-core
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

*Before, connect to **FTP** and check module name on folder **vendor/mageplaza/**